# Liferay 7 - Custom style for Blogs Aggregator

Tags: java, liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

Using the base portlet "Blogs Aggregator" to display a list of blogs entries, how can I apply a custom template to portlet ?

Unfortunately it isn't possible to use the ADT for this portlet.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite the JSP of the module. I think that's pretty much the only thing you can do at this moment, and at the same time, it makes your Liferay brittle when it comes to updating (i.e. if they change anything in the JSPs that you rewrite, it'll likely cause some problems for you) but it works.

Check out the [documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-core-jsps) and [Blade example](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/maven/overrides/module-jsp-override) to learn how to override a JSP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, now it makes sense. Thank you!